osgeo packages quit running in python evironment without error/warning
I am having problem with running gdal/ogr/osr in python environment. The program just stopped running until the line where I use any of these packages.It doesn't give any error or warning message. I can import all these packages fine.
Here is my setup:
python: 3.12.7
gdal: 3.9.2(install from build .wheel)
numpy: 2.2.0
The code is ran in a virtual environment.
I do have gdal cli installed and gdal3.9.1 version in my qgis installation. And I can run the same code in qgis python editor.
my gdal cli version is 3.2.2.
I tried deleting the virtual env and reinstall everything, which didn't work.
I downgraded to gdal: 3.8.4, which works fine. The problem is that it doesn't support numpy 2.0.
Example:
from osgeo import gdal, ogr

filepath = "filepath.tif"
print('here message can be printed okay')
gdal.Warp("warped_filepath.tif", 
        filepath,
        xRes=0.1,
        yRes=-0.1)
print("this message will not be printed and no new file generated")

This code will run and fail silently without any error when it goes to gdal.Warp function.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Try also with a simple example. Sometime the problem is caused by data (still a bug, but it helps for workaround). Sometime it is the OS (too much memory). Sometime conflicting libraries (and dll), maybe outside a virtual environment (various guides tell us to use wrong shortcuts, or hardcoding paths, as workaround, instead of trying to correct the real problem)

If you want gdal to raise exceptions using the python bindings, you should call gdal.UseExceptions() after importing gdal.
More info here: gdal python_gotchas.
In gdal 4.0 it is planned (but no planned date yet) to change the default behaviour so this is not necessary anymore.
Example:
from osgeo import gdal, ogr

gdal.UseExceptions()
filepath = "filepath.tif"
print('here message can be printed okay')
gdal.Warp("warped_filepath.tif", 
        filepath,
        xRes=0.1,
        yRes=-0.1)
print("this message will not be printed and no new file generated")

